# Issue with naming new column using aggregate

Tags: r

For some reason, `aggregate` is giving me the wrong column names, even though the data are still coming out correct.  Can anyone tell me why (am I doing something wrong)?

For example, with a dataframe `df`:

```
df <- structure(list(Site = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Sample = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Diameter = 1:6), .Names = c("Site", "Sample", 
"Diameter"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

which looks like

```
    Site Sample Diameter
1    1      1        1
2    1      2        2
3    1      3        3
4    2      1        4
5    2      2        5
6    2      3        6
```

I run the following code

```
# Add column to calculate area from diameter
df['Area'] = ((df['Diameter']/2)^2)*pi

# Subset sites
Site1 <- subset(df, Site == "1")

# Calculate total area for each site
Site1_area <- aggregate(Site1$Area, by=list(Sample=Site1$Sample), sum, na.rm=TRUE)

Site1_area
```

This gives the new dataframe `Site1_area` as

```
    Sample  Diameter
1      1 0.7853982
2      2 3.1415927
3      3 7.0685835
```

where the calculated areas have been preserved, but the column name is now incorrectly given as `Diameter` instead of `Area`.  I know I can rename this using

```
colnames(Site1_area) <- c("Sample", "Area")
```

but it seems odd to me that the column isn't being named correctly to begin with.  Can anyone tell me why?  Am I doing something incorrectly?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm thinking this is the wrong title for this question. Perhaps changing to "Problem with naming new column"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made an error that wasn't caught when you did this:

```
df['Area'] = ((df['Diameter']/2)^2)*pi
```

Should have been:

```
df[['Area']] = ((df[['Diameter']]/2)^2)*pi
```

After you did this you had:

```
> df
  Site Sample Diameter   Diameter
1    1      1        1  0.7853982
2    1      2        2  3.1415927
3    1      3        3  7.0685835
4    2      1        4 12.5663706
5    2      2        5 19.6349541
6    2      3        6 28.2743339
```

So you never really had a column named "Area". If you want the labeling to be simple then try the aggregate.formula method:

```
Site1_area2 <- aggregate(Area~Sample, data=Site1, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
> Site1_area2
  Sample      Area
1      1 0.7853982
2      2 3.1415927
3      3 7.0685835
```

Comment: Hey DWin, with your solution, the new dataframe "Site1_area" now gives the column name as "x" instead of "Area", so I still have to rename it.  Is that supposed to happen?  Is the renaming a necessary second step, or should the column name "Area" be preserved after aggregate?